# Regular expression error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Using the `RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$")]`, I want the user to enter digits up to 15 in length, which returns the error message *'Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number'* if this is not correct

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ("Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number")), Display(Name = "Contact Number"), RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$")]
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

If the user fails to do this I am left with the error message:

```
The field Contact Number must match the regular expression '^\d{1,15}$'.
```

instead of `'Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number'`...does anyone know why?
thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have assigned the `ErrorMessage` to the `RequiredAttribute` (which you absolutely don't need in this case because of the regular expression). So:

```
[Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number")]
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to place your message in `RegularExpression` attribute, not `Required` attribute.

You've added your error message to `Required` attribute, which means it will be displayed when the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter up to 15 digits for a contact number")]
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```