# From regular expression to a correct UI validation error

Tags: regex

We use a service that sends a list of fields required for a booking (of something..). 
The output looks like :

1. Field_1
   Validation: [-\s/0-9A-Z]{1,105}
2. Field_2
   etc..

On the UI we would like to map it to English text (or other languages, but let's assume English now). 
The UI validation error would be:

> "Please enter a valid format : Alphabetical characters and/or space from 1 to 105"

The idea would be to translate any regex into text..

I wanted to know, if this has already been tackled before?

Comment: You could just add the human readable error message to your list: Field_1 Validation[regex] Message: "...". But IMHO that is not too helpful. It would be more helpful to tell people what they're missing, e.g., "must have at least one digit", and for that you need to have multiple checks, one for each such error condition.

Comment: What language are you using?  "Language" isn't a very helpful tag.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296563/regular-expression-error-message

Comment: I don't mind which language, but more how it could be handled regardless on the language..
I removed the language tag..
Thank you for your answers ! by the way !

Comment: _"Please enter a valid format : Alphabetical characters and/or space from 1 to 105"_ - this would be an utterly poor error message, since it were to be understood as _… Alphabetical characters and/or space with character codes from 1 to 105…_. Correct English would be _1 to 105 alphabetical characters and/or spaces_.