# C# Attribute Error message isn't showing corectly

Tags: c#, regex, attributes

I have a error message in my attribute but when the condition is true I get a completely different error message.

I searched my solution for the string that i get back and its not found. It must be auto generated.

How do I get it to display the message I wrote and not this message that it gives

"The field Program Code must match the regular expression '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'".

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Only alpha numeric characters are allowed.")), Display(Name = "Program Code"), RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")]
    public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: that error generated by `RegularExpressionAttribute` not by `RequiredAttribute`. You do not specify `ErorrMessage` for `RegularExpressionAttribute` that's why you get default one.

Comment: See [Regular expression error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296563/regular-expression-error-message)

Comment: Thanks that did it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ("Only alpha numeric characters are allowed.")), Display(Name = "Program Code"), 
 RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = ("Only alpha numeric characters are allowed."))]
    public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Ill accepts in a few minutes when it lets me.