# ASP.NET CORE RegularExpression data annotation ignoring error message

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

I have a model called CreateStaffViewModel which has a data annotation for the password which checks the user has entered an upper, lower, numeric and special character and at least 8 characters long.
Along with a user friendly Error Message.

My problem is that on the view the Error Message is being ignored and the regular expression is being showed.

```
public class CreateStaffViewModel : StaffViewModel
        {
            [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*([^a-zA-Z\d\s])).{8,}$",
                ErrorMessage = "Must include upper, lower, numeric and special characters")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
```

[image]

How can I make the regular expression on the view display the user friendly error message.

PS. I have already viewed the answer [Regular expression error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296563/regular-expression-error-message) and implemented the answers. Which NONE have worked for me.

**UPDATE: View Code**

```
    <form asp-action="Register">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
                    @*<span  asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: You code is correct , I tested and it show the `Must include upper, lower, numeric and special characters` not the default error message .  Did you try to create a new simple project to test ? Make sure the model is the `CreateStaffViewModel ` in your view. Could you share a complete simple project that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Are you checking Model.IsValid in your controller? Would you mind posting the controller logic?

Answer (score 0):

In the razor view:

```cs
@Html.ValidationMessageForm(model => model.Password)
```

Comment: I've tried changing the code on the view. Had no effect. Same error message appears